# $\frac{{\sin \theta \cos \theta}}{1!}+\frac{{\sin 2\theta \cos ^2\theta}}{2!}+\frac{{\sin 3\theta \cos ^3\theta}}{3!}+...\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

I have tried replacing $\ x$ with $\cos x$ in the maclaurin series of $\ e^x$, but stuck with the $\sin$ terms. Is there any other method to solve this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try $x\rightarrow \cos \theta \cdot e^{i\theta}$ in the same Maclaurin series. Then the imaginary part is what you are looking for.

$$e^{\cos\theta(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)}=1+\frac{\cos\theta(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)}{1!}+\frac{\cos^2\theta(\cos2\theta + i\sin2\theta)}{2!}+\frac{\cos^3\theta(\cos3\theta + i\sin3\theta)}{3!}+...$$

Comment: i think it should be the imaginary part of $\ e^{\cos\theta(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)}-1$

Comment: Yes, that is what it should be. The result is $e^{\cos^2\theta}\sin(\sin\theta\cos\theta)$

Comment: @ApratimRanChak $z$ and $z-1$ have the same imaginary part.

Comment: Why my answer is being downvoted? I honestly don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Momo No clue. I did not downvote.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your "then take the imaginary part" works only for $\theta\in\Bbb R$, but, well, I too tend to assume that $\theta$ stands for a real number.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{ix} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^{n} \, x^{n}}{n!} = \cos(x) + i \, \sin(x)$$
$$e^{x \, e^{i \theta}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \, e^{i n \theta}$$
$$e^{x \, e^{-i \theta}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \, e^{-i n \theta}$$

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n} \, \sin(n \theta)}{n!} &= \frac{1}{2i} \, \left( e^{x \, e^{i \theta}} - e^{x \, e^{-i \theta}} \right) = \frac{1}{2i} \, e^{x \, \cos(\theta)} \, \left( e^{i \, x \sin(\theta)} - e^{-i \, x \sin(\theta)} \right)\\
&= e^{x \, \cos(\theta)} \, \sin(x \, \sin(\theta))
\end{align}

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^{n}(\theta) \, \sin(n \theta)}{n!} = e^{ \cos^2(\theta)} \, \sin(\cos(\theta) \, \sin(\theta)) $$

Comment: How is this answer different from my answer 30 mins ago?